# Table of contents always shown as {toc \o "1-3" \z}

Tags: microsoft-word

Why is the Table of Contents in Word shown as:

```
{toc \o "1-3" \z}
```

[image]

But when I copy this then it shows whole content on pasting.

How do I display table of contents properly?

Answer (score 2):

Your document has Word's field code display toggled on. Pressing Alt-F9 toggles the display to/from the field results and the field code.